# automatically show image dimensions (Height and Width) in a HTML 'p' tag - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm new with javaScript and I'm having trouble with this mixed code segment that I got off a couple of sites.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
$("ph&W").text(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = ("#hi");

</script>
```

Could you please correct this code segment, i'm sure it will help others to come :)
Thanks.

Comment: To be fair it does really look like it's parts of dead code stitched together. The Frankenstein's Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  $("#phW").html(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = ("http://www.google.com/images/logo.png");
```

HTML:

```
<p id="phW"></p>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LBkXA/

Comment: Thanks that does what's needed except where the 'img.src' is i need it to be an 'id' of a 'img' in HTML.

Comment: Lookup the jquery documentation. `$("#imageID").attr("src")`

Comment: where abouts do I insert that?

Comment: `img.src = $("#imageID").attr("src");`